# HMAC_KEY not set warning

Tags: python, pyro

Im trying [example from pyro docs](http://packages.python.org/Pyro4/intro.html#simple-example), and i get

```
argon@vprime:~/py/pyro$ python greeting.py 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pyro4-4.14-py2.7.egg/Pyro4/core.py:155: UserWarning: HMAC_KEY not set, protocol data may not be secure
  warnings.warn("HMAC_KEY not set, protocol data may not be secure")
Ready. Object uri = PYRO:obj_1e83aa04124a4e808be18c6ca839d5fd@localhost:48766
```

How to avoid of this? 
(This example, nevertheless, works)

Also, how to detach pyro's daemon's process?

And - [example with name server](http://packages.python.org/Pyro4/intro.html#with-a-name-server) doesnt work:

```
argon@vprime:~/py/pyro$ python name_server.py 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pyro4-4.14-py2.7.egg/Pyro4/core.py:155: UserWarning: HMAC_KEY not set, protocol data may not be secure
  warnings.warn("HMAC_KEY not set, protocol data may not be secure")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "name_server.py", line 11, in <module>
    ns=Pyro4.locateNS()                   # find the name server
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Pyro4-4.14-py2.7.egg/Pyro4/naming.py", line 323, in locateNS
    raise Pyro4.errors.NamingError("Failed to locate the nameserver")
Pyro4.errors.NamingError: Failed to locate the nameserver
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are should be Pyro4.config.HMAC_KEY='the_same_string_for_server_and_client' as stated... somewhere (lost it) in pyro-docs